# Perl regexp for "Reply-To: " then characters then only "@domain1.fr" or "@domain2.fr"

Tags: regex, perl, xregexp

I want to write a Perl regexp which gives a match if a string

1. begins with "Reply-To: "
2. continues with any number of characters
3. continues with only "@domain1.fr" or "@domain2.fr
4. ends with any number of characters

Examples :

- Reply-To: abc def@domain1      must match
- Reply-To: abc def@domain2      must match
- Reply-To: abc def@domain3      must not match

I tried

```
/^Reply-To: *(?!@domain1.fr|@domain2.fr)/
```

but

- Reply-To: abc def@domain1 doesn't match
- Reply-To: abc def@domain2 doesn't matches

The problem is to exclude from the match domains that are **different from domain1 AND domain2**. Because, if I want to exclude from the match domains that are different only from domain1, I type

```
/^Reply-To: *(?!domain1.fr)/
```

and it works perfectly.

Comment: I noticed you used a negative lookahead `?!`. Does that mean that conditions **2** and **3** is *exclusive or*?

Comment: `/^Reply-To: .*?\@domain(1|2)\.fr/`  Put parenthesis around what need be captured

Comment: Thank you for having answered but my real domains are not named domain1.fr and domain2.fr, they are named something like xxxx.fr and yyyy.fr.

Comment: Alright, then use `xxx|yyy`.  The point being that you can use [alternation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#Matching-this-or-that) to match either of patterns. If it's anything else it won't match.  This is what you ask for.

Comment: Once we're at it, for merely matching you'd use the _non-capturing_ parenthesis, `(?:...)`. So the regex is: `/^Reply-To: .*?\@(?:xxx|yyy)\.fr/`.  The `?:` after the opening paren makes `(...)` not capture, so they are used merely to group patterns

Comment: If you are going to use regex I suggest to get informed first. A very good starter is [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html), perhaps along with [perlrequick](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html).  The full reference is [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then the regex you're looking for is:

```
/^Reply-To: *.*(@domain1.fr|@domain2.fr)/
```

Comment: Your regexp gives a match for Reply-To : <characters>domain.fr or domain2.fr.

Comment: I want a regexp that gives a match for Reply-To : <characters>domain.fr different from domain1.fr and domain2.fr